# How to show $d(\exp_q)_0(v)=\frac{d}{dt}\Big|_{t=0} (\exp_q(tv))$?

Tags: riemannian-geometry

How to show
$$
d(\exp_q)_0(v)=\frac{d}{dt}\Big|_{t=0} (\exp_q(tv))
$$
where $q\in M$, $M$ is a smooth Riemannian manifold, and $v\in T_qM$. $\exp$ is exponential map, defined as
$$
\exp_q(v)=\exp(q,v)=\gamma(1,q,v)
$$
where $\gamma(t)$ is a geodesic satisfying $\gamma(0)=q, \gamma'(0)=v$.

This problem is from the Proposition 2.9 of Do Carmo's Riemannian Geometry.

[image]

Comment: Let $f\colon M\to N$ be a smooth map between two smooth manifolds and $m\in M,\ v\in T_m M$. Let $\gamma\colon (-1,1)\to M$ be a smooth curve such that $\gamma(0)=m,\ \gamma'(0)=v$. Then, $df_m(v)=(f\circ \gamma)'(0)$.